# Can compositing be displayed in the viewport render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, compositing-nodes

I have made an object glow using nodes and cycles render. when I hit the render button in the properties panel it glows fine but when I go into the rendered view it won't glow. Is this even possible?

Rendered when render button is clicked:

[image: Rendered when render button is clicked]

Rendered in viewport:

[image: Rendered in render view]

Answer (score 3):

No that can not be done. The compositer does not render in viewport. The viewport render is just a quick preview of the scene.

Comment: From digging around a bit, it appears that this is on a sort of unofficial todo list (mentioned [here](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/) and [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/GoogleSummerOfCode/2013/Ideas#Game_Engine)). There is work being done on the viewport for gsoc (possibly with custom scriptable viewport shaders), there might be more realtime emphasis when the bge is being brought up to date, and there are [mutters](https://developer.blender.org/T37562#18) about a compositor refactor. So hopefully this will be a feature soon :)